# Can i configure two different GA4 Tags config for one GTM?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

Can I track same event tags from GTM for different GA4 Tags?

I would like to have another GA4 for the same application but different environment.
If I configure new GA4 config tag, GTM should send data properly for both GA4's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently not. You need another ga4 event tag to fulfill this requirement.

But I think the easiest way is :

1. Create another GA4 configuration tag.
2. Export the current GTM container.
3. Copy all the tag in the JSON file and replace the measurement id to the new one.
4. Now you have two set of the GA4 events.

Downside for this is you need to maintain 2 set of GA4 tags in the future.

Comment: you can make it easier if you keep the number of tags to a minimum. Rather than making a tag for each distinct piece of tracking, it's best to have a few tags covering vast majority of tracking, using simple routing and structuring in the dataLayer.

Comment: Thank you! As I understand - I need to create new Tag manager container and import there data from my current container with changed measurement ID. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. As BNazqruk mentioned. That would be a better way but I guess this need a very structured dataLayer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a lookup table variable for your measurement ID for your configuration tag. For the lookup table variable, put your input as the page hostname for each environment and then output to each data stream measurement ID from GA4. That way you can just use one config for the different environments and then have one event tag that maps to the config tag.